# How to connect to an external oracle database from Docker

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, docker, networking

I have a docker image of spring boot application. I need to access to an external oracle database (hosted in 172.X.X.X) from my docker image. In order to access the database, I have to connect to VPN first.

Without using docker, I can set up VPN in my local machine and access to oracle database.

How can I achieve this by using docker?

Answer (score 0):

You still need access to the database from the host, and then tell docker to use your host network (`--network host`) when you run the container.

Comment: when i execute `docker run -d --network=172.X.X.X -p 8081:8081 myApp.jar`, i'm getting belllow error message `docker: Error response from daemon: network 172.X.X.X not found.` NOTE: 172.X.X.X is accessed only via VPN. So how can i connect to VPN from docker?

Comment: try with --network host and see if 172 is accessible